# Positioning of annotations in subplots

Tags: octave, matlab-figure, subplot

I have to generate a plot of different sensor data. These should be printed in subplot each.  After generating the plot it should be annotated with some rectangles to highlight different features. Afterwards, these rectangles should be annotated with a text, describing the belonging class with a short word.

Surprisingly the same code is working in another script, where I don't use subplots, but only a single specgram.
I already replace the annotation(h,...) with annotation(gcf, ...), which should be the same. Adding tempplot instead of h, which makes sense to me,

```
Sensorinput = rand(100,6);
Naminginput = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f'}
sampledExperiment = [10, 10, 0;
                 30,10, 1; 
                 50,10, 0; 
                 70,10, 1; 
                 ]

experimentnaming = {0, 'classA';
                1, 'classB'
                }

samplerate = 10;                    

h = figure;
for index = 1:1:length(Sensorinput(1,:))
  tempplot = subplot(length(Sensorinput(1,:)),1,index);  
  plot(Sensorinput(:,index));
  title(Naminginput(index));
  pos = get (tempplot, 'position')
  step = pos(3)/length(Sensorinput(:,index));


  for index=1:1:length(sampledExperiment)

    annotation(h, "rectangle",[pos(1)+step*sampledExperiment(index,1),pos(2),step*sampledExperiment(index,2),pos(4)]);
    y  = ylim;
    for namingindex=1:1:length(experimentnaming(:,1))  
      if experimentnaming{namingindex,1}==sampledExperiment(index,3)
          text(sampledExperiment(index,1)/samplerate,y(2),experimentnaming(namingindex,2),'rotation',90);
      end
    end

  end

end
```

I expect the boxes having the same height than the underlying subplot. Also, I am expecting the text (which is obviously printed as a stack) as an annotation to the box.
But this is the result I currently get: [wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldIbU.png). Also, the boxes do not zoom correctly, when I resize the window. [wrong_small_window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml57z.png). 
This is mainly, what is working: [working with single figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6uNG.png). Draw rectangles with the full height of the subplot and add text. This is created with the same code, but without subplots.

Hopefully you can help?

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking, perhaps you could annotate your image / put a hand-made drawing / example of what is correct? Also, there's no point to your code here, since it's not a standalone example. Consider writing a minimal working example one could copy / paste and run directly in matlab. However, as general advice, if you want fine-tuned manual control, I recommend using `axes` directly to place "subplots" rather than the `subplot` command; you can use `line` to draw your boxes manually where you want them;

Comment: (cont.) and lastly, if you expect text to move along x axis and it's not, presumably you then meant `namingindex` in your `text` argument rather than `index`, since the latter doesn't change inside your inner for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added some codes for an example and an image, of the program without the subplot, where it is working nicely. Hopefully this is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying with a working example. Here's another simpler / more visually pleasing way to do it using the `area` function.

```matlab
Sensor = struct ('input', num2cell (rand (6, 100), 2), ...
                 'name',  {'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'});
Experiment = struct ('samplestart', { 10     ,  30     ,  50     ,  70}, ...
                     'samplewidth', { 10     ,  10     ,  10     ,  10}, ...
                     'classindex',  { 0      ,  1      ,  0      ,  1 });

ClassNames     = {'classA', 'classB'};
ClassColours   = {[1.0, 0.8, 0.8], [0.8, 0.8, 1.0]};

NumPlots = length (Sensor);
for n = 1 : NumPlots
  subplot(NumPlots, 1, n); hold on;
  for m = Experiment
    Hndl = area ([m.samplestart, m.samplestart + m.samplewidth], [1, 1]);
    set (Hndl, 'facecolor', ClassColours{m.classindex + 1});
    Hndl = text (m.samplestart+2, 1.2, ClassNames{m.classindex+1});
  end
  plot ([1:100], Sensor(n).input, 'k', 'linewidth', 2);
  text (-7.5, -0.25, Sensor(n).name, 'fontsize', 16, 'fontweight', 'bold');
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I updated another class so it is working like your example.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to get what I want by using a direct rectangle instead of annotation rectangle. With this type, I am able to use the data space instead of figure space and everything is fine.

```
Sensorinput = rand(100,6);
Naminginput = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f'};
sampledExperiment = [10, 10, 0;
                     30, 10, 1;
                     50, 10, 0;
                     70, 10, 1];
experimentnaming = {0, 'classA';
                    1, 'classB'};
samplerate = 10;

h = figure;
for index = 1:1:length(Sensorinput(1,:))
    tempplot = subplot(length(Sensorinput(1,:)),1,index);
    plot(Sensorinput(:,index));
    title(Naminginput(index));
    pos = get (tempplot, 'position')
    step = pos(3)/length(Sensorinput(:,index));

    for index=1:1:length(sampledExperiment)        
        rectangle('Position',[sampledExperiment(index,1),0,sampledExperiment(index,2),1]);
        y  = ylim;
        for namingindex=1:1:length(experimentnaming(:,1))
            if experimentnaming{namingindex,1}==sampledExperiment(index,3)                    
                text(sampledExperiment(index,1)+0.5*sampledExperiment(index,2), y(2),experimentnaming(namingindex,2),'rotation',90);
            end
        end            
    end        
end
```

I also mixed up the data space with the figure space while plotting the text.

[image: works as expected]